# upgrade node 0.10 to 0.12.x on RHEL

Tags: node.js, rhel5

Since we do not have any updates available via EPEL repo, what would be a clean approach to upgrade node to 0.12.x from 0.10 on RHEL 5

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **[`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)** package to upgrade the node version by using these commands (from [David Walsh's blog - Upgrade Node.js via NPM](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)) to first install the package:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
```

which you can then upgrade the node version as follows:

> Type `n` to prompt selection of an installed node. Use the up / down
>   arrow to navigate, and press enter or the right arrow to select, or ^C
>   to cancel:

```
sudo n

  0.11.16
ο 0.12.0
  0.12.1
```

> Use or install the latest official release:

```
sudo n latest
```

> Use or install the stable official release:

```
sudo n stable
```

> Switch to the previous version you were using:

```
sudo n prev
```